# Is there a difference between zero resistance and dissipationless transport?

Tags: condensed-matter, electrical-resistance, superconductivity, topological-insulators

Zero resistance in superconductors is what I have learned in university and in textbooks. But in the field of topological insulators, I have seen the phrase "dissipationless transport" get thrown around a lot without an obvious explicit statement that there is zero resistance conduction at the edges of a topological insulator due to the spin-momentum locking. Is there a difference between these ideas?